# ASP.NET Core Web API on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS doesn't get SQL connection to MSSQL 2008 server

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, ubuntu-14.04, entity-framework-core

I created a small ASP.NET core web api using MVC and Entity Framework. I managed to build and publish it for/to Ubuntu.

When I enter the url swagger shows up as expected. But when I try to access a resource (click a link to the web api) it throws an exception in the log files indicating that it can not access the database.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught) ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (No such device or address) ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: No such device or address
   at System.Net.Dns.HostResolutionEndHelper(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Dns.EndGetHostAddresses(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.d__22.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle..ctor(String serverName, Int32 port, Int64 timerExpire, Object callbackObject, Boolean parallel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.d__3`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.d__15`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter.WriteObject(TextWriter writer, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.ExceptionTrackingMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.RequestTrackingMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.d__2.MoveNext()
```

Well, the database is on a different machine. It is pingable, responding from another machine and even with commandline tool you can query the database from the linux commandline.

The connection string is the same as on the windows machine definind ip address, server name, user id and password.

Are there any dependencies that has to be installed or is there a need for some (not that well documented) configuration changes I am missing?

---

There are already a couple of questions and answers on that but no answer was able to solve the problem for me.

Things I tried so far:

- check if config files are copied to the server -> they are
- hardcode connection string -> works from Win7 but not on Ubuntu
- adding explicit port to the connection string -> no change
- adding semicolon at the end of the connection string -> no change
- check if TCP/IP and named pipes are enabled on the SQL Server -> they are
- ping the server from the Ubuntu machine -> SQL server is pingable
- test it with Debug and Release version -> same error
- update all Nugets to neweset versions -> no change
- adding System.Data.SqlClient to the project.json -> no change
- use TSQL from the Ubuntu shell to test the server -> using TSQL it works
- out of curiosity I followed [that guide](http://guywyant.info/log/206/connecting-to-ms-sql-server-from-ubuntu/) and got it working -> still same error

---

Update:

There is not much configuration. The code is simple in the Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddDbContext(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        //configs of other parts
    }
```

in appsettings.json

```
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=DatabaseName;user id=*****;password=*****"
    },
```

I blanked out the ip address, gave another db name and inserted some stars for the user id and passwort.

None the less it works on my win7-x64 machine as is.

Comment: where you store connection string? maybe publishing doesn't include config file? Also if you use different setting/code based on Environment (Prod, Dev) this may affect.

Comment: show your code that read settings and create connection

Comment: so far it is a small project, only one config file (appsettings.json), no different versions. Config file was copied, checked it. Other settings (e.g. for swagger) from the appsettings.json are perfectly used. So config file error may could be excluded.

Comment: Where is the SQL Server? On your win7 machine? Are TCP/IP and Named Pipes enabled on the SQL Server?

Comment: No, database is running on a seperated Windows Server 2008 not on my local win 7. Will check it if TCP/IP and NamedPipes are enabled. Will need some time to grad the server admin :-). Am I right that TCP/IP could be enabled since I get the connection between database server and my local development win7 IIS?

Comment: @WEI_DBA Hi WEI_DBA, checked it. Named Pipes and TCP/IP are enabled on the SQL Server.

Comment: How are you starting your API? `dotnet api.dll` or `dotnet run`?  Are you running the process as the same user which can connect using SQL?  Does it work running as root/sudo?  Just to encourage you, I have what looks like the same code running no problem.  This is a generic SQL error I have seen on Windows too, usually when client config like named pipes/TCP is wrong, but you've checked that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was simply a mistake by myself.

I scaffolded the DbContext from an existing database. By that I missed that scaffolding adds a HARDCODED connection string into the OnConfigure method. This connection string pointet too a different (no longer existing) database.

So all my approaches to connect or changing the connection strings in the appsettings.json etc just got overwritten by the hardcoded connection string and for that failed.